# Move items in half circle just like an endless listview

Tags: android, geometry, items, listings

Hello guys I have tried to make a list like that. But nothing find. The items shown in list moves up and down. Main question is how to set items like a circle. This is possible in iphone, but in android how to achieve this. [image]

Comment: Why this is not a real question. This is view of mobile which is already exist in iphone. If i am trying to make it in android, then how it does not look like a real question.

Comment: Ya, its great. I saw it.