# How to make a Circular Shaped scrolling listview ? - Android

Tags: android, list, listview, view, geometry

(After writing, I realize the question is too big for most to read. If you can take my word as to why I posted a seemingly duplicate question, Head over to last part !)

[Circular ListView (Items on Half Circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253295/circular-listview-items-on-half-circle)

[image]

The above link takes you to and almost exact same question and what we're both trying to do, (me,here and the guy on that link) ... Is achieve a literally Circular shaped ListView - See the pic. Exactly that.

***Why am I asking this question again?***
That question has been dead since nearly 6 months, so I can't possibly hope to contact the people who answered/asked ( I tried.)

Further, the answer of the question gives the correct answer - Completely working.
However, It needs API 11 + ..
Considering ~30% of my existing app's user base is below API 11, I need to create this exact listview for at least API 8 + ...

***Short Explaination***
What the guy in that answer is doing:

Below is the custom textview:

```
public class MyView extends TextView {

    private static final int MAX_INDENT = 300;
    private static final String TAG = MyView.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.save();
        float indent = getIndent(getY());
        canvas.translate(indent, 0);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public float getIndent(float distance){
        float x_vertex = MAX_INDENT;
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float y_vertex = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2 / displayMetrics.density;
        double a = ( 0 - x_vertex ) / ( Math.pow(( 0 - y_vertex), 2) ) ;
        float indent = (float) (a * Math.pow((distance - y_vertex), 2) + x_vertex);
        return indent;
    }
}
```

And here's the listview:

```
public class HalfCircleListView extends ListView implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    public HalfCircleListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnScrollListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        //Ignored
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        absListView.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

Basically he's figuring out the point on a parabola, Placing a list item there, Then going forward, checking the current position of this textview, compare it with other textviews(The ones after it) and then place them accordingly.

Pretty straightforward... My question isn't that big actually.

***Here's the problem:***

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.save();
    float indent = getIndent(getY());
    //Part of the magic happens here too
    canvas.translate(indent, 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Huge as* question, but my problem is just one line:

```
float indent = getIndent(getY());
```

The getY(); function requires minimum API 11+.
Is there an identical function for API 8 + ?

Also, is there a better way to implement this ? (if you bothered to read the code :-D)
If you know of any other sexy custom listviews, Please post it here.

Any input will be appreciated.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

how about getTop()?
the getY() is equivalent to the translationY property plus the current top property,
assuming you are targeting for API that is below 11 the translationY should be unchanged
due to the fact that the setTrnaslationY function is also API 11+, so there you have it...