# how to draw scrollable arc menu

Tags: android

Is there any way to design scrollable Arc menu? I have searched a lot but cannot find any solution for scrollable arc menu. I know we can design and develop an arc menu with fixed menu items, but what if we have number of menu items?

I need to allow user to scroll through them using arc menu,

Please help me with these issue.

Thank you

Comment: please refer this link it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253295/circular-listview-items-on-half-circle