# How to implement a circular RecylerView / ListView using any CircularLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

I want to make a `CircularListView` that will be coming from corner click of screen and only half list item should be visible before scrolling. And the item in list is in Dynamic nature - [image].
And I have used these libraries from github but not getting any efficient solution from any of them. These libraries are:

1. [RamotionCircleMenu](https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu-android) -> In this library custom layout is not possible.
2. [HellocslCursorWheelLayout](https://github.com/BCsl/CursorWheelLayout) -> Here no customization is possible, Item Selection is poor.
3. [JungHsuanCircularList](https://github.com/JungHsuan/CircularUI) -> When you add items in bulk the item overlaps, circle radius not get updated according to item count(still this one is better)
4. [LukedeightonWheelview](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView) -> Only `Drawable` as item is allowed.

So please let me know if anyone is having solution for it. I want the solution for dynamic item count, custom layout as item and smooth scroll of `List/RecyclerView`.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to improve the formatting of your post. However, most of your library links aren't valid URLs. Please replace them with the correct ones, so that people can help better.

Comment: You have to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16366645/5815673 and also this https://github.com/dkmeteor/CircleList

Comment: @Shailesh the solution you are redirecting to contains only a textView while I'm asking for any custom complex view.

Comment: you have to use that for implement circular view and do some custom code for your custom layout. First you have to try then still you face any issue then share it here

Comment: Did you look at this? https://github.com/kapil93/Circular-Layout-Manager

Comment: thank you all finally this library helped me out. (https://github.com/SachinR90/VWUiDemo).  And I got the solution as per my requirement after little bit changes.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTurkovsky https://github.com/kapil93/Circular-Layout-Manager also helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using to this layout manager to show recycler view in android

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloper98/CircularRecyclerView

[image]